# Applying the MIN aggregate function to a BIT field

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to write the following query:

```
SELECT   ..., MIN(SomeBitField), ...
FROM     ...
WHERE    ...
GROUP BY ...
```

The problem is, <s>SQL Server does not like it, when I want to calculate the minimum value of a bit field</s> it returns the error `Operand data type bit is invalid for min operator`.

I could use the following workaround:

```
SELECT   ..., CAST(MIN(CAST(SomeBitField AS INT)) AS BIT), ...
FROM     ...
WHERE    ...
GROUP BY ...
```

But, is there something more elegant? (For example, there might be an aggregate function, that I don't know, and that evaluates the logical `and` of the bit values in a field.)

Comment: @Adam Robinson: Obviously, `Operand data type bit is invalid for min operator.`

Comment: Don't know about more elegant but it is a *bit* shorter. `cast(min(SomeBitField+0) as bit)`

Comment: @Andomar: Obviously if you already know the problem, yes, but others with similar issues may search on the *error message*, so information like that needs to be in the question.

Comment: This is just stupid.  There is no reason why data type bit should be invalid for min/max, since *obviously* 0 < 1 and thus bit values are orderable.

Comment: Also, I *always* run into this sort of issue when I'm *forced* to aggregate a field that I *know* (due to constraints) will always be the same value, so why can't there just be an aggregate function FIRST() or something that just returns the first or *any* instance of the field?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Since there are only two options for `BIT`, just use a case statement:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ....) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS 'MinBit'
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

This has the advantage of:

- Not forcing a table scan (indexes on `BIT` fields pretty much never get used)
- Short circuiting TWICE (once for `EXISTS` and again for the `CASE`)

It is a little more code to write but it shouldn't be terrible.  If you have multiple values to check you could always encapsulate your larger result set (with all the `JOIN` and `FILTER` criteria) in a `CTE` at the beginning of the query, then reference that in the `CASE` statements.

Comment: There are three options for `bit` if it is nullable.

Comment: @martin - Good point.  It wouldn't change the query in this circumstance though unless they want to handle `NULL` in a specific way, since we are testing equality

Comment: If the `bit` column consisted entirely of `NULL` values then `MIN` should return `NULL`.

Comment: I must be a "lesser" programmer, but I would have like to have seen a full example of the `select 1 from ...` subquery.  It does not quite make sense.

Comment: @Vaccano - `SELECT 1 FROM Outertable WHERE bitfield=1`

Comment: The original question included a GROUP BY though. You need to include the group by criteria in the WHERE.

Comment: This requires rewriting almost the entire query within the column expression, doesn’t it? If the query is expected to have filtered the data to less than a few hundreds of rows, the `CAST(MIN(CAST(«expression» AS INT)) AS BIT)` method is a lot easier to think about and maintain.

Answer (score 188):

One option is `CAST(MIN(SomeBitField+0) AS BIT)`. It reads well, with less noise (which I would qualify as elegance).

That said, it's more hack-ish than the `CASE` option. And I don't know anything about speed/efficiency.

Comment: @Ben, Thanks a lot, This alson help me for my SQL Query.

Comment: @Ben, do you have some documentation of **+0** ?, tried to look for it but not find anything, just for references :)

Comment: @FranciscoSevilla I believe it's because of the implicit precedence conversion: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Presumably is must be cast back to BIT again? `CAST(MIN(SomeBitField+0) AS BIT)`

Answer (score 9):

This query is the best solution:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(BitField+0) = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS MyColumn
 FROM MyTable
```

When you add the BitField+0 it would automatically becomes like int

Answer (score 7):

```
select min(convert(int, somebitfield))
```

or if you want to keep result as bit

```
select convert(bit, min(convert(int, somebitfield)))
```

Answer (score 7):

This small piece of code has always worked with me like a charm:

```
CONVERT(BIT, MIN(CONVERT(INT, BitField))) as BitField
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the following
**Note:** Min represent And aggregate function , Max represent Or aggregate function

```
SELECT   ..., MIN(case when SomeBitField=1 then 1 else 0 end), MIN(SomeBitField+0)...
FROM     ...
WHERE    ...
GROUP BY ...
```

same result

Answer (score 2):

AVG(CAST(boolean_column AS FLOAT)) OVER(...) AS BOOLEAN_AGGREGATE

Give a fuzzy boolean :

- 1 indicate that's all True;
- 0 indicate that's all false;
- a value between ]0..1[ indicate partial matching and can be some percentage of truth.