# SQL Aggregate bit columns to single bit result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have some rows in the following format:

[image]

I want a SQL query which will group the above rows by EntityId and aggregate the bit columns in the following way:

- Submitted: 0 if any row for a given EntityId is 0, else 1
- Reviewed: 0 if any row for a given EntityId is 0, else 1
- Query: 1 if any row for a given EntityId 1, else 0

I know I can do this by casting the bit column as an int and using Min/Max but it feels like a bit of a hack. I think I am having a slow day and missing the obvious solution...

What is the best way to do this?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2, although a general SQL method would be best.

Update:

The desired result set for the rows above would be:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997721/applying-the-min-aggregate-function-to-a-bit-field.

Comment: To clarify, can you share your desired resultset?

Comment: Yep, the cast to `int` is about the best that you can do. Which is a shame because elsewhere in the documentation, `bit` is claimed to be a numeric type, so it should make sense to call `MIN` or `MAX` directly against such values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think casting to an `int` is probably best overall as there are no bitwise aggregates, anything else will also be "hacky".

For fun this should work without casting the bit fields;

```
select
  EntityId,
  1 ^ count(distinct nullif(Submitted, 1)),
  1 ^ count(distinct nullif(Reviewed, 1)),
  count(distinct nullif(Query, 0))
from t
group by EntityId
```

Comment: Thanks. I like your alternative! However I think casting wins in the readability stakes...

Answer (score 3):

Relying on implicit data conversion:

```
select entityId
,max(1*submitted)  as submitted
,max(1*reviewed) as reviewed
,max(1*query) as query
from sd_test
group by entityId
order by entityId;

select entityId
,max(sign(submitted))  as submitted
,max(sign(reviewed)) as reviewed
,max(sign(query)) as query
from sd_test
group by entityId
order by entityId
```

Health Warning:

> ### SIGN: Arguments
>
> numeric_expression Is an expression of the exact numeric or
>   approximate numeric data type category,  except for the bit data type.

It works fine for bit data type though. Since bit can be either 0 or 1, sign will always return 1 or 0 (though in reality, it could return -1,0,1)

```
select sign(cast(1 as bit)); --returns:1
select sign(cast(0 as bit)); --returns:0
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct you want something like this:

**Test data:**

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(EntityId INT,Submitted BIT, Reviewed BIT,Query BIT)
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
        (36,1,0,0),
        (52,1,0,0),
        (52,1,1,0),
        (56,1,0,0),
        (56,1,1,0),
        (57,1,0,0),
        (57,1,1,0)
```

Then a query like this:

```
SELECT
    table1.EntityId,
    MIN(CAST(Submitted AS INT)) AS Submitted,
    MIN(CAST(Reviewed AS INT)) AS Reviewed,
    MAX(CAST(Query AS INT)) AS Query
FROM
    @tbl as table1
GROUP BY
    table1.EntityId
```

Comment: Isn't that just the same as casting the bit to an int?

Comment: @gvee : yes it is. A total brain fart from my side. Thanks for the feedback. Update the answer

Answer (score 1):

You want bits in the result, right?

```
SELECT
    t.EntityId,
    CAST(MIN(CAST(t.Submitted AS INT)) AS BIT) AS Submitted,
    CAST(MIN(CAST(t.Reviewed AS INT)) AS BIT) AS Reviewed,
    CAST(MAX(CAST(t.Query AS INT)) AS BIT) AS Query
FROM YourTable t
GROUP BY t.EntityId
```

Answer (score 0):

For a bit of fun I threw this together. It doesn't use any casting or converting unlike previous answers...

```
DECLARE @tbl table (
   EntityId  int
 , Submitted bit
 , Reviewed  bit
 , Query     bit
);

INSERT INTO @tbl
  VALUES (36, 1, 0, 0)
       , (52, 1, 0, 0)
       , (52, 1, 1, 0)
       , (56, 1, 0, 0)
       , (56, 1, 1, 0)
       , (57, 1, 0, 0)
       , (57, 1, 1, 0)
;

SELECT DISTINCT
       base.EntityId
     , Coalesce(submitted.Submitted, 0) As Submitted
     , Coalesce(reviewed.Reviewed  , 0) As Reviewed
     , Coalesce(query.Query        , 1) As Query
FROM   @tbl As base
 LEFT
  JOIN @tbl As submitted
    ON submitted.EntityId = base.EntityId
   AND submitted.Submitted = 1
 LEFT
  JOIN @tbl As reviewed
    ON reviewed.EntityId = base.EntityId
   AND reviewed.Reviewed = 1
 LEFT
  JOIN @tbl As query
    ON query.EntityId = base.EntityId
   AND query.Query = 0
;
```

Results:

```
EntityId    Submitted   Reviewed    Query
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
36          1           0           0
52          1           1           0
56          1           1           0
57          1           1           0
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer returns 1 for the Submitted and Reviewed columns if any row for a given EntityId has these columns set to 1, rather than 0 if any row for a given EntityId is set to 0. Toggling the Submitted/Reviewed values gets the desired result set.