# Set value for a new column based on GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql

I've below mentioned SQL requirements. I've been able to create the query for the 1st & 2nd requirement. But, my main requirement is the 3rd point. And, I need help in 3rd one only, please.

***Requirements:-***

1. (Done) Products should be grouped by its "Comment" column's value.
2. (Done) Get the total number of products under each group of same comment.
3. (Need advice) Based on value in 'IsApproved' column, there should be a new column - 'Group_Approval'.

   - If any product, under a group of same comment, has (bit column) "IsApproved" = 0, then update the 'Group_Approval' = 0. Else update 'Group_Approval' = 1.

Excluding 3rd point, ***Current query* :-**

```
SELECT P.ProductID, COUNT(P.ProductID), PA.Comment, P.IsApproved
FROM
    Products P 
    INNER JOIN ProductApproval PA ON P.ProductID = PA.ProductID
WHERE
    P.ProductID = '123456'
GROUP BY
    P.ProductID, PA.Comment, P.IsApproved
```

***Current Result:*-**

```
ProductID   Total_Count_Same_Commented_Product       Comment           IsApproved

12345                 1                      Use it after 2 months.        0
12345                 1                      Cannot be used till 2020.     1
12345                 1                      Use it after 2 months.        1
```

As per 3rd requirement, below mentioned is what I actually want. ***Required Result :-***

```
ProductID   Total_Count_Same_Commented_Product       Comment        Group_Approval

12345                 2                      Use it after 2 months.        0
12345                 1                      Cannot be used till 2020.     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT P.ProductID, COUNT(P.ProductID), PA.Comment, MIN(P.IsApproved)
FROM
    Products P 
INNER JOIN ProductApproval PA ON P.ProductID = PA.ProductID
WHERE
    P.ProductID = '123456'
GROUP BY
    P.ProductID, PA.Comment
```

Should do what you want if IsApproved can only be 0 or 1. If it can be a range of values then you'd put a CASE statement within the MIN function and set the values as needed.

Comment: Thanks George but I'm getting error with your solution - "Operand data type bit is invalid for min operator". 'IsApproved' column is BIT type and thus it will only be either 1 or 0.

Comment: I'm not familiar with bit fields but you might then need to look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997721/applying-the-min-aggregate-function-to-a-bit-field

Comment: Thanks for the link for the cases of BIT type. I did a small edit in your solution and it worked for me. Thanks a lot, again.