# SQL Grouping with a logic check on another column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Lets say that I have the following table:

```
id    param    result
1     AAA      TRUE
1     AAA      FALSE
1     AAA      FALSE
1     BBB      TRUE
1     CCC      TRUE
2     AAA      TRUE
2     CCC      TRUE
3     AAA      FALSE
3     AAA      FALSE
3     AAA      FALSE
3     CCC      TRUE
3     BBB      TRUE
```

Is there a way to group by the [param] column so that the [result] will show TRUE if any of the corresponding results are TRUE and show FALSE if none are TRUE? Below is an example of what I am aiming for:

```
id    param    result
1     AAA      TRUE
1     BBB      TRUE
1     CCC      TRUE
2     AAA      TRUE
2     CCC      TRUE
3     AAA      FALSE
3     CCC      TRUE
3     BBB      TRUE
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997721/applying-the-min-aggregate-function-to-a-bit-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sketch of code that will work.  You just need to put in the right constants for `result`:

```
select id, param,
       (case when sum(case when result = TRUE then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then TRUE else FALSE
        end)
from table t
group by id, param;
```

SQL Server does not have a native boolean type and doesn't understand "true" and "false".  For some representations (such as `'TRUE'` and `'FALSE'`), the following will work:

```
select id, param, max(result) as result
from table t
group by id, param;
```