# Is there any reason why min and max not working on bit fields

Tags: sql, sql-server

Probably I'm missing something, but it still looks strange for me why it's impossible to use `max` and `min` aggregates on bit fields. So if I try to do something like this:

```
declare @temp table (data bit)

insert into @temp
select 1 union all
select 0

select max(data) from @temp
```

I'll get an error `Operand data type bit is invalid for max operator.` But if I do something like this:

```
declare @temp table (data bit)

insert into @temp
select 1 union all
select 0

select top 1 * from @temp order by data desc
```

It works fine, so SQL Server **does know how to sort bit fields**. But the possibility to order data implies that we can get a maximum or minimum.
What's the reason behind this restriction then?

Comment: Maybe not an answer, but as a workaround you can simply use `CAST(Data AS TINYINT)`, that should be fine enough, no?

Comment: yep, of course I know the workaround :) But I wonder why this restriction. And also how it affects index behaviour

Comment: it would mess with the index usage, but "A more efficient way would be using TOP 1 / ORDER BY instead of MAX and MIN. Ordering, unlike MAX and MIN, does work on bits": FROM (http://tech.pro/tutorial/1419/10-things-in-sql-server-which-don-t-work-as-expected)

Comment: Point 5 on here: http://tech.pro/tutorial/1419/10-things-in-sql-server-which-don-t-work-as-expected highlights this problem, and offers more workarounds, but doesn't explain the underlying reason.

Comment: Some slightly interesting comments in [Applying the MIN aggregate function to a BIT field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997721/applying-the-min-aggregate-function-to-a-bit-field)

Comment: I suppose noone except Microsoft guys knows the reason. 

But according to [this ticket](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/749263/aggregate-functions-on-bit-columns-min-and-max) the only answer from Microsoft is something like "It is by design, we don't have any plans to implement aggregation functions on bit columns in the immediate future"

Comment: I guess bits are often used as a boolean (True/False), and you don't aggregate a boolean . You can count how many of each but aggregating them doesn't make sense. Also peraps it has something to do with the 'packed' storage model - anywhere from 1 to 8 bits are stored as only one byte - they're all packed in there.... thats my 2 cents.

Comment: A SELECT TOP(1) .. ORDER BY uses physical Sort operator; an aggregate function will use Stream or Hash aggregate operator; hence the difference. It seems Stream aggregate don't do bits. If I may guess (w/out actually looking at the code) this would have to do someting with physical implementation of the BIT datatype. However, COUNT works...

Comment: @dean hence I wonder if this physical implementation of BIT datatype could affect the performance of the index on bit fields?

Comment: I think not. If you use DBSS PAGE to look at the NC index on bit col vs tinyint, they're same.

Comment: Sry, should've been DBCC PAGE, can't edit any more..

Comment: This is probably an oversight in the initial design and now they don't touch this. The SQL team rarely improves features after v2 except for good reasons. Also T-SQL language investments are near zero.

Comment: The `bit` datatype is somewhat schizophrenic in that it tries to copy some of the semantics of boolean. Maybe it was decided that MAX(true/false) wouldn't make any sense. In practice it is inconvenient though.

Comment: Surely the MAX(bitfield) can only be 1 and the MIN(bitfield) can only be 0.

Answer (score 4):

Unless we can get some inside information from the SQL Server team we might have to accept that sometimes the answer is just "because". The documentation is quite clear though, for example the MSDN page for [MIN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179916.aspx) states;

> MIN can be used with numeric, char, varchar, uniqueidentifier, or
>   datetime columns, but not with bit columns.

My guess (yes, I am prepared to be flamed for hazarding a guess in an SO answer!) is that the benefit doesn't outweigh the risk of the change to the code. What exactly would the benefit be?

You're not the first to ask but the response to [Aggregate functions on BIT columns: MIN and MAX](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/749263/aggregate-functions-on-bit-columns-min-and-max) on MS Connect suggests it's not likely to change.

Comment: "What exactly would the benefit be?" Cleaner code. Returning a column of the correct datatype without a double CAST.