# During GroupBy I need to get only one result, but i am getting duplicates

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

[image]

it is an example to understand easily what i need
in the Below pic i have put the the two table datas,

in the tableB is linked with tableA,

From tableA ID--> 1 is fail in one subject

ID--> 2 is pass in all subject

ID--> 3 is fail in 2 subject.

so i need the exact result like this

[image]

the query i used is

```
Select A.ID,A.name,case when B.Result='fail' then 'Fail' else 'Pass' End  from tableA A 
inner join
TableB B ON B.id=A.Aid
```

by using this the name is get repeating. , but i need only one name with one result

Comment: I don't see the connection between the two tables, at least not in a way which explains the problem with duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN MIN(BitField+0) = 1 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END AS MyColumn
 FROM MyTable
```

from the following link
[Applying the MIN aggregate function to a BIT field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997721/applying-the-min-aggregate-function-to-a-bit-field)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to get the worst result among the results of each student ("fail" if there's one "fail", "pass" otherwise). You can do that with `group by` and `min` as grouping function

```
Select  A.ID, A.Name, min(B.Result)
from    TableA A 
join    TableB B
on      A.ID = B.Aid
group by A.ID, A.Name
```

This works because in alphabetical order `"fail" < "pass"`

Comment: haii thanks for result, but how can i take min , if it is 3 subject ok if it is 4 or 5 or 6 how can we take.(equal pass and equal fail can come know 3 pass 3 fail) how to overcome

Comment: `min(B.Result)` will get the minimum result among _all_ the results of each `A.ID, A.Name` couple, so if they're 3 or 4 doesn't make any difference

Comment: ok, min means for example if it have 6 subject 3 paper pass and 3 paer fail. then wht will take( PASS or FAIL)

Comment: `min("pass", "pass", "pass", "fail", "fail", "fail") = "fail"`. The only way it can be "pass" is when *all* the results are "pass"

Comment: if it is 0 and 1 ie, 0 for fail and 1 for paass then the min operator will not work

Comment: Why not? Isn't `min(0, 1) = 0`?

Comment: it is a bit field not an integer

Comment: for a bit field you can refer following answer

Answer (score 1):

```
;with TableA(Id,Name,Class)
As
(
SELECT 1,'Johny'  ,6 Union all
SELECT 2,'George',6  Union all
SELECT 3,'Jisha',6
)
,TableB(Id,Aid,Subname,Result)
AS
(
SELECT 1,1,'SEcinece','Fail' UNION ALL
SELECT 2,1,'Social'  ,'Pass' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1,'English' ,'Pass' UNION ALL
SELECT 4,2,'SEcinece','Pass' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,2,'Social'  ,'Pass' UNION ALL
SELECT 6,2,'English' ,'Pass' UNION ALL
SELECT 7,3,'SEcinece','Fail' UNION ALL
SELECT 8,3,'Social'  ,'Fail' UNION ALL
SELECT 9,3,'English' ,'Pass'
)
,Final
AS
(
SELECT *,CASE WHEN Dt.CNT<3 Then 'Fail'
                WHEN Dt.CNT=3 Then 'PASS' END AS FinalResult
                 FROM
(
SELECT A.Id,A.Name,B.RESULT,COUNT(B.Result)OVER(PARTITION BY B.AId,A.Name ORDER BY B.AId)AS CNT,
ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY B.AId,A.Name ORDER BY B.AId )AS Seq FROM TableA A
INNER JOIN TableB B
ON A.Id=b.Aid
WHERE B.Result='Pass'
)Dt

)
SELECT Id,Name,FinalResult AS Result FROM Final WHERE Seq=1 ORDER BY 1
```

---

OutPut

```
Id  Name    Result
1   Johny   Fail
2   George  PASS
3   Jisha   Fail
```

Answer (score 0):

By my understanding,

```
create table #temp(id int, name varchar(1))
insert into #temp values(1,'p')
,(1,'p')
,(1,'f')
,(2,'p')
,(2,'p')
,(2,'p')
,(3,'p')
,(3,'f')
,(3,'f')

select id, min(name) from #temp group by id, name

with cte as (
select id, name, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by id order by name) rn from #temp group by id, name
) select id, name, rn from cte where rn = 1
```